# Azure CLI to change machine type after VM created

Tags: linux, command-line, azure

How to change machine type with Azure Bash CLI after (a Linux) VM has already been created? Need to bump up a level when I need the CPU power.

PS. This cannot be done on-the-fly but have to do after power-off, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure CLI command 'az vm resize' will handle this. This operation can be completed on a running VM. The VM reboots after the command is entered.

The command syntax is:

```
$ az vm resize --name <VM-Name> --resource-group <Resource-Group-Name> --size <New-VM-Size>
```

See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-resize

Comment: Just confirmed that the VM reboots when running the command to change VM size.